# Is it possible to get rid of all commits that are ahead of my branch?

Tags: git

New to GIT and I've made a total mess of things.

I was trying to merge my colleagues changes in, and somehow made my git tree look like below. I was trying to rebase my local changes to some changes he's recently made to the master branch. For some reason, I thought I needed to merge and I must have ended up merging the wrong branch. (or something?)

[image]

Anything above the AddNewListingPage, I want to delete. How do I get to a stage the merge never happened and the top 4 commits do not appear at all?

Comment: well i deleted everything and cloned it again and that seemed to have fixed it, although just wondering if there's another solution. I guess the problem I have is to delete local commits that haven't been pushed into the remote yet

Comment: What branch were you working on, doesn't look like the screenshot above shows where `HEAD` is.

Comment: @R0MANARMY - the branch I was working on was AddNewListingPage - The HEAD is the bolded text

Comment: I'm not really sure what's pointing to the merge commit, it looks unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do things without merge commit, you can do `git pull --rebase`. This removes your changes, pulls remote changes and reapplies your changes like if you committed after pulling.

Answer (score 0):

Simply reset the refs to where they were before, see `git help revisions` for allllll the ways you can do it, depending on how much you've inadvertently done while trying to recover the safest might be

```
for b in branch1 branch2 branch4 branch4 etc; do
    git checkout -B $b $b@{yesterday}
done
```